# SSRS: one or more parameters were not specified for the subreport located at

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have one summary report with one parameter
it calling subreport with two parameters and values are passing summary report dataset values.

Subreport is displaying data for some of the summary report parameter values only for some parameter values not showing data

error:

> one or more parameters were not specified for the subreport located at

I subreport report parameter properties.

Subreport should display for all parent parameter values

Comment: does the subreport has anything set in the "available values" property of either of the parameters? If so then then it might be that your master report is calling the subreport with invalid parameters. You can test this easily by removing the available parameters restriction.